# How to create shortcode to display all posts in each category

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have this problem: i have made a custom page with his own set of categories. In a shortcode i want to get all the categories and in the categories i want all the post related to that category.

```
function innovatiewerkplaats_sort($atts, $content = null){

    global $post;

    $terms = get_terms('innovatiewerkplaats_categories'); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

    $nieuws = '';

    foreach($terms as $term):
        $nieuws .= '<div class="one">
                        <h2>Thema <strong>'.$term->name.' id='.$term->term_id.'</strong></h2>
                    <div class="wrapper">';

        $category_query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'innovatiewerkplaats',
            // 'category' => $term->term_id,
            'category_name' => $term->name,
            // 'cat'  => $term->term_id,
        );

        query_posts($category_query_args);

        if( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            $post_home= get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'post-home');
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '' );
            $url = $thumb['0'];
            $excerpt = get_the_content();
            $excerpta = preg_replace("~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $excerpt);

            // $ter = wp_trim_words( apply_filters( 'rpwe_excerpt', $excerpta ), $args['length'], '…' );
            $nieuws .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'" class="one_fourth workplace">'.$term->term_id.'<span class="img" style="background:url('.$url.') no-repeat center center; background-size:cover;"></span><span class="titel">'.get_the_title().'</span><p></p><span class="more">Lees meer</span></a>';

        endwhile; endif;

        $nieuws .='</div></div>';

    endforeach;

    return $nieuws;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Don't use [`query_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Please take a look discussion [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/18731).

Here sample approach related to your issue to generate all posts base on their category, then display via shortcode for later.

1. Inside a function, you should query all posts first ( use `wp_query` or `get_posts` ),
2. Get related category by post id inside query loop. If term taxonomy, use `get_the_terms`.
3. Build an array of query data with key ( in this case, we use term slug ) to grouping posts.
4. Then take those data for outside loop, and output them with
   simple loop.
5. Build a shortcode by function `add_shortcode` ( this code use simple shortcode only ).

---

```
/** Shortcode [my_shortcode_posts] */
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode_posts', 'so36133962_get_all_posts_by_category' );

/**
 * All posts by category
 * build query by get_posts
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
function so36133962_get_all_posts_by_category( $attr, $content = null )
{
    /**
     * Build custom query
     *
     */
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'your-post-type', // set your custom post type
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        /** add more arguments such as taxonomy query i.e:

                'tax_query' => array( array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'genre', // set your taxonomy
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'comedy','drama' ) // set your term taxonomy
                ) )
        */
    );

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    /**
     * Prepare Posts
     *
     */
    $result = array();

    // The Loop
    if ( $posts->have_posts() )
    {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() )
        {
            $posts->the_post();
            /**
             * Get all item in a term taxonomy
             *
             */
            $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'your-taxonomy' /* set your term taxonomy */ );
            if ( ! $categories )
                continue;

            foreach ( $categories as $key => $category )
            {
                $term_name = $category->name;
                $term_slug = $category->slug;
                $term_id   = $category->term_id;
            }

            /**
             * Set thumbnail background cover
             * Use Featured Image
             */
            $img_cover = '';
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
            {
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );
                if ( ! empty( $image_url[0] ) )
                {
                    $img_cover = '<span class="img" style="background:url( ' . esc_url( $image_url[0] ) . ' ) no-repeat center center; background-size:cover;">';
                }
            }

            /**
             * Format html content
             *
             */
            $format = '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" class="post-%3$s">%4$s%2$s</span></br><span class="content-%3$s">%5$s</span></br><span class="more">%6$s</span></a>';

            /**
             * Formatted string post content
             *
             */
            $content = sprintf( $format,
                get_permalink(),
                get_the_title(),
                get_the_ID(),
                $img_cover,
                get_the_excerpt(),
                __( 'Read More', 'text-domain' )
            );

            /**
             * Set an array of each post for output loop
             *
             */
            $result[ $term_slug ][] = array(
                'post_id'      => get_the_ID(),
                'post_content' => $content,
                'term_name'    => $term_name,
                'term_id'      => $term_id
            );
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // post reset

    /**
     * Check existing output
     *
     */
    if ( ! $result )
        return;

    /**
     * Output loop
     *
     */
    $output = '';
    foreach ( $result as $slug => $data )
    {
        $count = count( $data );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ )
        {
            /**
             * Set data as object
             *
             */
            $post = ( object ) array_map( 'trim', $data[ $i ] );

            if ( 0 == $i )
            {
                /**
                 * Set category id and name
                 *
                 */
                $output .= '<div id="term-category-' . absint( $post->term_id ) . '">';
                $output .= '<h3>' . esc_html( $post->term_name ) . '</h3>';
            }

            /**
             * Set post id and content
             *
             */
            $output .= '<div id="post-' . absint( $post->post_id ) . '"><p>' . $post->post_content . '</p></div>';
        }

        $output .= '</div>';
    }

    return $output; // complete
}
```

You can change element structures as your needs. As note, with this code, no duplicate posts in each category, and make sure you change the values such as post type and taxonomy as commented in code. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code and thanks for the explanation of the code! i learned something today :)